# CloudZoom with Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, fancybox

I'm a little new to javascript as I mostly just fool around with CSS styling when developing web pages.

I ran into a problem trying to integrate Fancybox with Cloudzoom. I've been trying to follow the directions as directed here: http://blog.codestars.eu/2010/cloud-zoom-in-der-fancybox/

I'm able to get the effect to work perfectly except for one small error-- for some reason (all my images are in galleries for easier use scrolling through fancybox), the zoom only ever shows the first image in the series.

If someone could help me sort through this? Preview any of the galleries here: http://bit.ly/LaPzEH

Here's the tidbit I think is just slightly off - I think it has something to do with the href line in this code being off:

```html
    $j('a[rel=gallery]').fancybox({ 
    padding: 0,
    overlayColor: '#'+$j('#skin_color').val(), 
    transitionIn: 'fade',
    transitionOut: 'fade',
    overlayOpacity: .9,
    onComplete    :   function(arg) {
        $('#fancybox-img').wrap(
         $('<a>')
         .attr('href', $(arg[0]).attr('href'))
         .addClass('cloud-zoom')
         .attr('rel', "position: 'inside'")
    );
    $('.cloud-zoom').CloudZoom();
}
});
```

Any an all help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Got it working by changing

```html
$(arg[0]).attr('href')
```

to

```html
this.href
```

As an aside (because I couldn't find many cloudzoom/fancybox threads) you can also change the position from inside to right/left etc. by editing the JS code for fancybox to have the fancybox-inner display as visible rather than hidden.

Comment: where do you get `#fancybox-img` from?

Comment: can you show final code including the html? i cannot seem to get mines to work. I am using fancybox gallery too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the idea is to wrap the `#fancybox-img` selector with an anchor with `class="cloud-zoom"` and with the same `href` attribute of the anchor that opened fancybox like

```
<a href="{same as anchor}" class="cloud-zoom" rel="position: 'inside'">
 <img id="fancybox-img" src="{big image}" alt=" " />
</a>
```

... so *Cloud Zoom* can work on the specific image, then I would re-write the `onComplete` callback like :

```
'onComplete' : function(){
  $('#fancybox-img').wrap(
    $('<a />')
     .attr('href', this.href) // this.href gets the "href" of the current image
     .addClass('cloud-zoom')
     .attr('rel', "position: 'inside'")
    ); // wrap
  $('.cloud-zoom').CloudZoom();
} // onComplete
```

(not idea what the heck `onComplete : function(arg)`  would do but in any case it would be better to use `'onComplete' : function(currentArray, currentIndex)` for the sake of standard fancybox code)

**SIDE NOTES**:

1. You are loading two versions of jQuery (1.4.2 and 1.7.1) when you actually need a single instance (ideally the latest version) to avoid unexpected errors.
2. You are using fancybox v1.3.0 ... it wouldn't hurt to upgrade at least to [v1.3.4](http://fancybox.net/)
3. Set all your fancybox API options between quotes like

   ```
   "padding": 0, // it's OK 0 without quotes (integer and Boolean values go without them)
   "overlayColor": '#'+$j('#skin_color').val(),  
   "transitionIn": 'fade',
   "transitionOut": 'fade',
   "overlayOpacity": .9,
   "onComplete": ...etc
   ```

   there are known issues (mostly with IE) because that (fancybox v1.3.x)

Comment: That changed worked! Thanks so much for helping me sort that out.

Reason that some of the codes (jQuery and fancybox) are a little out of date is because I got a ready to go theme with those plugins already installed right in and needed to do some further customization. I didn't want to update to latest version and risk having all the custom code built into the plugin breaking. Thanks again!

Comment: this does not work for fancybox 2. I have been trying. also someone keeps ending my post everytime i put a question up. how do i make it work with a gallery?