# Adding zoom capability to Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I wish to add the zoom capability to fancybox similar to Demo 1 here http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/powerzoomer.htm

The button helper available in fancybox are not adequate as the enlarge button only goes to the maximum size of the image.

Although I’ve hardcoded this `fancybox-manual-b` if I get it working I’ll be doing this dynamically.

First I tried adding an id to each image that appears in a fancybox and adding these to `jQuery(‘#Pic_1, #Pic_2, #Pic_3, #Pic_4’).addpowerzoom` but that didn’t work I think because the mouse hover action is already occupied by fancybox thus conflicting.

Ideally this is how i'd like implement this but haven't got it to work

So now I’m attempting to pass the image ref into an iframe

On clicking “Zoom in Fancybox” a new blank tab opens and the fancybox opens in the parent but no image just Hello Holly.

Just to complicate matters I need to make this work using jquery version 1.4.4 as this is used within WordPress.

Please suggest what I'm doing wrong

Parent html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>fancyBox - Fancy jQuery Lightbox Alternative | Demonstration</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

   <!-- Add jQuery library -->

   <script type='text/javascript' src='../js/jquery/jquery.js'></script>
    <!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

    <!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.6" media="screen" />

    <!-- Add Button helper (this is optional) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.2" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.2"></script>

    <!-- Add Thumbnail helper (this is optional) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.2" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.2"></script>

    <!-- Add Media helper (this is optional) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.0"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/ddpowerzoomer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('a').each(function(){

         var Href = $(this).attr('href');
         if ((Href.match(/jpg/i)) || (Href.match(/jpeg/i)))
           {
           $(this).attr('class', "fancybox");

           }
          else
          {
          alert ("jessica");
            $(this).attr('target', 'blank');
          }

        });
      $('a > img').each(function(){

        if($(this).parent('td'))
          {

            if($(this).parents().attr('target') == 'blank')
              {
              alert("Hello Holly " + $(this).attr('target'));
              $(this).removeAttr('target');

              }
            $(this).parent().attr('class', "fancybox-buttons");
            $(this).parent().attr('data-fancybox-group', "gallery" );

          }



    });

        $('.fancybox').fancybox();

         /*
          *  Button helper. Disable animations, hide close button, change title type and content
          */

         $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,

            helpers : {
               title : {
                  type : 'inside'
               },
               buttons  : {}
            },

            afterLoad : function() {
               this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
            }
         });
            $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open({
                    href : 'hollyframe.html?1_b.jpg',
                    type : 'iframe',
                    padding : 5
                });
            });


});

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td><a id="pic_1" href="1_b.jpg" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="1_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
              </td>
              <td><a id="pic_2" href="2_b.jpg" title="Etiam quis mi eu elit temp"><img src="2_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a id="pic_3" href="3_b.jpg" title="Cras neque mi, semper leon"><img src="3_s.jpg" alt="" /></a></td>


              <td><a id="pic_4" href="4_b.jpg" title="Sed vel sapien vel sem uno"><img src="4_s.jpg" alt="" /></a></td>

            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div>
              <h3>Etiam quis mi eu elit</h3>
              <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  <a href="http://localhost/dweb/2692.htm">www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/</a> consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam <a id="pic_5" href="5_b.jpg" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit">Graphic A</a> quis mi eu elit tempor facilisis id et neque.
              </p>
              <p>
              <a href="jessica-alba-102.JPEG" title="Jessica Alba">Graphic A</a>
              </p>
              <p>
              <a id="fancybox-manual-b" href="javascript:;">Zoom in Fancybox</a>
              </p>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

hollyframe.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var myPic;
   function GetPic(){
     var url= window.location.href;
     var  bits =url.split("?");
     myPic = bits[1];


    }
   jQuery(document.createElement("img")).attr({src: myPic, id: 'Pic'});

    jQuery('#Pic').addpowerzoom({       defaultpower: 2,
        powerrange: [2,5],
        largeimage: null,
        magnifiersize: [100,100] //<--no comma following last option!
    });


    </script>
    </head>
  <body>
       <p>Hello Holly</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**update code following JFK sugestions**

i'v beeing playing with this all day and am strugiling to get it working

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#Pzoom').fancybox(
          beforeShow: function(){
               $('#fancybox-img').wrap(
        $('<a />')
       .attr('href', this.href) // this.href gets the "href" of the current image
       .addClass('power-zoom')
       .attr('rel', "position: 'inside'")

     $(this.href).addpowerzoom({
        defaultpower: 2,
        powerrange: [2,5],
        largeimage: null,
        magnifiersize: [100,100] //<--no comma following last option!

            }); 
  ); // wrap
    };
  );          
});  // ready

  </script>
```

Comment: Well, fancybox v2.0.6 requires jQuery v1.6 or later to work properly so you would need to update your WP jQuery version. You could find many articles or forum answers of how-to do that like http://wordpress.org/support/topic/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-jquery-in-wp or http://mhuntdesign.com/blog/jquery/change-default-jquery-version-wordpress/. Then you can try binding your images to the `addpowerzoom` plugin using fancybox `beforeShow` callback.

Comment: This is an example using cloudzoom http://stackoverflow.com/a/11399590/1055987 where the script is bound using the `onComplete` call back (v1.3.4) but you may use `beforeShow` for v2.0.6 to achieve the same result.

Comment: I looked at Cloudzoom but the concept of having a lager image behind the small image is not possible but i will investigate the concept of wraping the image.

Comment: As for updating Jquery in WP I'm trying to avoid doing that mainly because I don't totally understand what other WP pluugins use jQuery so didn't want to break stuff i'm not responsible for. Thanx for the help

Comment: the cloudzoom example was for code reference only (I never suggested to switch to it.) Personally I don't think that upgrading jQuery will break other stuff as long as you just load a single instance of it ... and for sure you will hardly have fancybox v2.x working properly with the version of jQuery you have.

Comment: JFK I've been trying to follow your suggestion but am not getting var var Please look at updated code (I've cut it down some what to 1 link to 1 image with an ID = "Pzoom" without the beforeShow code clinking the link displays the image in a fancybox but i'm clearly missing somthink.
PS. I know you were not suggesting i used cloudZoom. Thanx