# cloudzoom inside fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Hi i am trying to make cloudzoom (innerzoom) work with fancybox. I followed this [link](http://blog.codestars.eu/2010/cloud-zoom-in-der-fancybox/)

But i keep getting this error in console as i move the cursor over the zoomed image:

```
TypeError: opts.itemArray[opts.itemCurrent] is undefined
```

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
'onComplete'    :   function(arg) {
    // Here does the magic starts
    $('#fancybox-img').wrap(
        $('<a>')
        .attr('href', $(arg[0]).attr('href'))
        .addClass('cloud-zoom')
        .attr('rel', "position: 'inside'")
    );
    // That's it
    $('.cloud-zoom').CloudZoom();
}
 });
    });
</script>
```

Anchor tags go like this:

```
                    <a href="images/usr/scarvezoom1.jpg" class="fancybox">
                    <img src="images/usr/scalf1.png" alt="" />

                    </a>
```

What wrong i am doing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CloudZoom with Fancybox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392637/cloudzoom-with-fancybox)

Comment: ... the solution is for fancybox v1.3.x so make sure you are using that version otherwise you may need to tweak the code.

Comment: have you solved this. i am having same problem